# How $\mathbb{R}$ is union of countable collection of disjoint component intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

*Mathematical analysis by Tom Apostol*

> **Definition**. let $S$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R$. An open interval $I$ (which may be finite or infinite) is called component interval of $S$ if $I \subset S$ and if there is no open interval $J \ne I$ such that $I \subseteq J$ and $J \subseteq S$.

Now, I can't understand what it says. If I take $S =(1,2)$ , then is $(1,2)$ its only component interval?

Then how can $\Bbb R$ be a union of such open intervals?

Examples will be very helpful.

Comment: $\mathbb R=(-\infty,\infty)$ is also an open interval. (The definition is more interesting for disconnected open sets, like $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$.)

Comment: Yes, if $S = (1,2)$ then it has exactly one component interval, namely $(1,2)$. It is therefore the union of this one interval.

Comment: Can you come up with an open set with infinitely many component intervals, by the way?

Comment: Regarding your last question, could it be that the statement is rather: Any **open subset of** $\mathbb R$ is the disjoint uinon of countabl ymany component intervals?

Comment: Note that the term "countable" is slightly ambiguous, since some use it to mean "countably infinite" and others use it to mean "at most countable" (i.e. possibly finite). Hopefully, your book is consistent with itself, though it's usually clear from context.

Comment: @columbus8myhw  union of intervals (n, n+1) , n is positive integer, is an open set with countably infinite component intervals. But this is very obvious example.  Can I get few good examples? I can't think of any.

Comment: @divya How about $(.1,1)\cup(.01,.1)\cup(.001,.01)\cup\dotsb$? Or the union of every other set in that. Or, for a more complicated example, the complement of the Cantor set (if you've learned about that) — between any two connected components is another connected component. Interestingly, all of those examples only had at most _countably many_ connected components…

Comment: @columbus8myhw I am not comfortable with concept of connectedness now. But first example is very good. Thanks.

Comment: @divya In $\mathbb R$, a connected set is just an interval. The Cantor set is just weird.